# Difficulty with drawing rectangles from a seperate class in Xna?

Tags: c#, xna

I am working on a class for creating easy in game menus. I am able to draw the rectangles for buttons and draw the textures. But when I try the hover select feature the rectangle appears to be some place other than the texture. I programmed it so when the mouse hovers over one of the button rectangles the button's texture changes. < This feature doesn't work. It only works when I hover over a certain place on the screen. I need help. Btw I am a beginner at this. I think that all the rectangles are draw in the middle of the screen because they don't really draw correctly. If you want more specific details I will be glad to provide them. 
Please do help of you can. Thanks

```
enter code here
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (SelBaNum == 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < recNum; i++)
                spriteBatch.Draw(BaseButton, buttonList[i], Color.White);
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < recNum; i++)
            {
                if (i != RectangleNum)
                spriteBatch.Draw(BaseButton, buttonList[i], Color.White);
                else
                spriteBatch.Draw(SelectButton, buttonList[i], Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the draw method in my class. recNum is the number of rectangles to be drawn. RectangleNum is the index of the rectangle the mouse is over. SalBaNum is a byte that tells me whether the mouse is over a rectangle.

```
enter code here
            InstMenu.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

this line of code is what runs the method I placed this in the draw method on my Game1 class.

```
enter code here
    public void Update(MouseState mouse)
    {

        Rectangle mouseRec = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 2, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < recNum; i++)
        {
            if (buttonList[i].Contains(mouseRec))
            {
                SelBaNum = 1;
                RectangleNum = i;
             }
            else
            {
                SelBaNum = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is were SalBaNum is given a value. The method above a is also in my class that I am programming.

It doesn't let me post images.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: At least, you need to provide the relevant code. How d you draw the rectangles (including the full stack from `Game.Draw` to a class method) and how do you determine the hover state?

Comment: How do you synchronize the variables between your classes? Especially `SalBaNum` and `RectangleNum`. They look like class variables. If they exist in both classes, then they are independent from each other unless you implemented some synchronization. Btw, you should add a `break;` after `RectangleNum = i;`. Your first method can be simplified a lot. Something like `for(...) {Texture2D tex; if(i == RectangleNum && SelBaNum != 0) tex = SelectButton; else tex = BaseButton; spriteBatch.Draw(tex, buttonList[i], Color.White); }

Comment: @NicoSchertler the 2 methods above are in the same class so those are the same variables (SalBaNum and RectangleNum).
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for others who will read this.
The problem was with where the rectangle for the mouse was being placed. It has nothing to do with the code I showed. This is just so that no one gets confused.

Thanks